# Is there a difference from making potash from lye or ash?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any difference (besides the obvious extra production step) when making potash from lye (produced from ash) or making it directly from ash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None at all. Potash that comes from Lye and Potash that comes from Ash is - to my knowledge - the same type of item.

Comment: Turning the ash into lye and the lye into potash adds a work task. On the plus side, that means you get twice the training out of one unit of wood. On the down side, that means it takes twice as long.

Comment: @Shadur To avoid talking about ash and lye: Does Lye-based Potash and Ash-based Potash stack?

Comment: @user1337 last time I checked, stacks can only separate and never combine.

Comment: They're interchangeable, but they're always single units that go into any bar/block pile or container.

Comment: The only time it stacks is by buying it from embark, but AFAIK the entire stack is consumed to make one bar of soap, so it's not worth buying more than one.